# CSS fade children when hovering over parent div, then change again when hovering over child

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an effect like the one on the social media buttons on this website: http://www.goldsquare.co/about (the icons under the picture of the girl). My CSS now gets the buttons to fade to gray when I hover over the parent div, but the individual buttons don't turn black when I hover over them like they should.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="social-media-icons">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fa {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.fa:hover {
  transition: background 0.2 ease;
  background: black;
}


.social-media-icons:hover a {
  transition: background 0.2s ease;
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

You can see it in action at this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brettfisher/fcn4d097/8/
How do I get the desired effect? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***By adding*** `!important` on `.fa:hover`. You could achieve the expected result.

***Check the following fiddle:***

```css
.fa {
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 15px;
      width: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: black;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .fa:hover {
      transition: background 0.2 ease;
      background: black !important;
    }
    
    
    .social-media-icons:hover a {
      transition: background 0.2s ease;
      background: #cccccc;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <div class="social-media-icons">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
    </div>
```

***Read more about `!important` [here](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)***

Answer (score 0):

give !important to override `.social-media-icons:hover a` property

```css
.fa {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.fa:hover {
  transition: background 0.2 ease!important;
  background: black!important;
}


.social-media-icons:hover a {
  transition: background 0.2s ease;
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="social-media-icons">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```css
.fa {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.social-media-icons:hover .fa{
  background: #cccccc;
}
.social-media-icons:hover .fa:hover{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="social-media-icons">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a correct css [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)  to let the specific one overwrite the other style. (carefully to use `!important`)

Also, if you want to imitate more accurately, you need to move the `transition` outside the `:hover` style.

```
.fa {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transition: background 0.2s ease;
}

.social-media-icons a.fa:hover {
  background: black;
}


.social-media-icons:hover a {
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0dpeaj1x/